# MYSQL Query Split 16 rows into 2 Teams

Tags: mysql

i have a maximum of 16 rows in the table i want 50% of the rows to be Team 1 and the other 50% to be Team 2 in a random order in. (8 random player in team 1 and 8 random players in team 2)

At this moment I got this:

```
UPDATE active_lobby SET Team = 1, OpponentsTeam = 2 WHERE LobbyID = :LobbyID

UPDATE active_lobby SET Team = 2, OpponentsTeam = 1 WHERE LobbyID = :LobbyID
```

But I want it in 1 Query, how can I do this?

Comment: For a random effect, you may have to generate a number and assign it to each of the 16 entries in a lobby, then using some selection process to divide them evenly (perhaps sorting the random number). This would certainly take more work than a single UPDATE statement. You might want to consider temp tables, or another field for the random number.

Comment: i have a maximum of 16 rows in the table but i want 50% of the rows to be Team 1 and the other 50% to be Team 2

Comment: You may use `select ...order by rand() limit 8` to chose players for team 1 and assign the rest to team 2